# how to download pictures from sd card to phone?

Tags: usb

I have a droid turbo and i bought a sd card reader to plug in an sd card from my game cameras into my phone so i can see these pictures without bringing my laptop to my cabin.  But i cant find anything on any file manager that can move these pictures to my phone from the sd card?

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! Is the card recognized as such (if not, you might need a specific, so-called "OTG cable")? Can you somehow browse the pictures?

Answer (score 1):

Try connecting another card reader and/or SD cards from a different manufacturer, it seems to be a frequent problem with Droid Turbo. AFAIK Kingston SD cards work more often then not.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of card reader is it? Is it made for your android? If not, it may need to be powered and your android isn't giving it enough power.

Typically when a 3rd party storage device is connected via micro-USB to an android device, the android will recognize it and you can navigate to it via the file browser. It may be considered a USB device though, so go through the root of the device to make sure it's not actually showing up.

Comment: it is called bone view and the package says made for android